# Inserir conteúdo de um arquivo HTML em uma DIV - jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um Sistema *GED* aqui para a empresa onde trabalho (bem simples, apenas para organizar melhor).

Estou desenvolvendo as telas primeiro, pra depois conectar com o BD e fazer as coisas funcionarem.

Eu tenho um menu que fica a esquerda com os links para navegar entre as páginas. A direita eu insiro o conteúdo das páginas em uma DIV chamada `#conteudo`, pra isso estou utilizando a função `load()` do jQuery. Conforme abaixo:

```
// Carrega o conteúdo das páginas dentro da div#conteudo    
$('.carrega_pagina').click( function(){ 

    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // pega o valor do atributo href da âncora clicada
    $('#conteudo').load(href);
    return false;
});
```

Isso tem funcionado bem, porém, ao clicar nos links umas 8-10 vezes ou mais, a tela solicitada demora a aparecer (é como se o navegador tivesse travando), além disso, o navegador chega a consumir até 70% da CPU quando solicito uma página (lembrando que isso tudo só ocorre após navegar várias vezes entre as páginas, quando dou um *refresh* na página tudo volta ao normal).

Queria saber se existe uma maneira melhor de inserir o conteúdo das outras páginas nessa DIV.

Comment: Provavelmente você está carregando um `javascript` que adiciona a função nos itens do menu. Conforme mais cliques você fizer, mas funções você adicionará aos itens e mais requisições esses itens irão fazer. O ideal é você utilizar uma requisição simples (pode ser `$.GET`) e carregar somente o que precisa. (Sem os JS já adicionados).

Comment: Tenta usar `html()` no lugar de `load()`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, é exatamente o que está acontecendo! Coloquei um alert no success do $.ajax e vi que cada vez que clico em um link a requisição é feita outra vez e vai incrementando...

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer com $.get? Outra dúvida, eu estou inserindo meu arquivo de script junto as páginas porque tentei fazer antes sem inserir e não funcionou as funções que tenho nas páginas solicitadas. Fazendo com $.get mesmo sem inseri-los novamente as funções irão funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece pois durante do `.load( URL )` você está trazendo alguns códigos `JavaScript` repetidos. Isso faz com que os elementos do menu fiquem adicionando mais e mais eventos de clique.

Esses eventos são adicionados tantas vezes, que ao invés de fazer uma requisição, você pode chegar a fazer 100 requisições de uma só vez. Claro que vai depender da quantidade de vezes que você clicar.

Para corrigir isso, é necessário que você filtre o que vai adicionar, por exemplo:

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="content">
            <p>The content of the document...</p>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            /* Carrega a página */
            $("#menu li a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.get( $(this).attr("href") , function(result){
                    let d = document.createElement("div");
                    d.innerHTML = result;

                    /* Adiciona o conteúdo da div#content da página dois na div#content da página atual */
                    document.querySelector("#content").replaceWith( d.querySelector("div#content") );

                    /* Executa todos os javascript que está dentro da div#content */
                    document.querySelectorAll("#content script").forEach( script => eval(script.innerHTML) )
                });
            })

            /**
             * Utilize o .on para elementos dinâmicos
             * Dessa forma, o jQuery irá verificar todos
             * os eventos "click" e depois irá verificar
             * se o evento percente ao elemento #btnTest
             * caso pertença, executa a função
             */
            $("body").on("click", "#btnTest", function() {
                alert( $(this).attr("data-msg") )
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="content">
            <p>Tudo certo</p>
            <button type="button" id="btnTest" data-msg="O JavaScript está funcionando.">Alerta</button>

            <script>alert("JavaScript liberado")</script>
        </div>

        <script>
            /* Carrega a página */
            $("#menu li a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.get( $(this).attr("href") , function(result){
                    let d = document.createElement("div");
                    d.innerHTML = result;

                    /* Adiciona o conteúdo da div#content da página dois na div#content da página atual */
                    document.querySelector("#content").replaceWith( d.querySelector("div#content") );

                    /* Executa todos os javascript que está dentro da div#content */
                    document.querySelectorAll("#content script").forEach( script => eval(script.innerHTML) )
                });
            })

            alert("JavaScript repetido")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado! Funcionou tudo perfeitamente, agora sem engasgos. =)

Answer (score 0):

Um alternativa é usar o próprio Ajax para fazer isso. O segredo é setar o `dataType` como "html", assim:

```
$('.carrega_pagina').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            $('#conteudo').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Agora faça os testes com múltiplos clicks e veja se atende melhor que o `.load()`

Comment: Ricardo, obrigado pela resposta. Eu fiz exatamente como você mencionou, mas continuou da mesma forma :(